# Why do I get error AADSTS65001 when using scope user.readwrite.all when I have admin consent

Tags: c#, openid-connect, microsoft-graph-api, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am creating an c# Web application with azuread. The application will let Azure ad administrators manage the users of a tenant. For this I need specific grants from the tenant of the user signing in.

I got the code working for most scopes like 'user.readwrite' and 'directory.readwrite.all'. But when I add the scope 'User.ReadWrite.All' I get the following error:

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the
>   application with ID '*Client application ID*'. Send an
>   interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

The user in question is the owner of the application from https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/
In this application I added the scopes: Mail.Send , User.Read , User.ReadWrite , Directory.ReadWrite.All and User.ReadWrite.All.
For the last 2 scopes, admin consent is needed.

But to force admin consent, even though the user is the owner. I used this URL to give my admin and all users in the tenant consent to the application with the above scopes.

> login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=*Client
>   application Id*&state=adminconsentstate&redirect_uri=*uri of my local
>   webapp*

In the Web application I connect with Azuread with Microsoft endpoint v2.0.

> login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=*Client
>   application
>   Id*&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+email+profile+offline_access&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3d...&prompt=select_account&redirect_uri=*Redirect
>   Url*&post_logout_redirect_uri=*Logout Redirect Url*

I use the following code to get an Accesstoken.

```
string userObjectId = "User Object Id Guid";
HttpContextBase baseContext = context.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase;
var tokenCache = new SessionTokenCacheMSAL(userObjectId,baseContext);

ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(_applicationSettings.ClientId,redirectUri.ToString(),new ClientCredential(_applicationSettings.AppKey), tokenCache);

var scopes = new List<string>();
scopes.Add("User.Read");
scopes.Add("user.readbasic.all");
scopes.Add("User.ReadWrite.All");
scopes.Add("Directory.ReadWrite.All");

var runTaskAcquireToken = Task.Run(async () => await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(scopes.ToArray(), context.Code));
runTaskAcquireToken.Wait();
var result = runtask.Result;
```

When requesting the Accesstoken and scope 'User.ReadWrite.All' is used, I get the error 'AADSTS65001' above. When I Remove the scope 'User.ReadWrite.All', I can view users, get DirectoryRoles and Organizations/tennants.

The weird thing is that the scope 'Directory.ReadWrite.All' also needs the same admin consent as 'User.ReadWrite.All' according by Microsoft.

source:

> http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes

Any help solving my issues would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Martijn, I don't have a comment on your issue with the scopes, but I was wondering, are you making the Microsoft Graph calls with an HTTP client, or the Microsoft Graph client library?

Comment: Here is a sample code that describes the flow for admin consent on behalf of his organization: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-admin-restricted-scopes-v2

Comment: Looks like you're doing everything right to me. Let me see if I can repro.

Comment: I took the exact same steps as you, and it worked fine for me.  If you'd like me to debug a bit further, could you please provide correlationId's and timestamps for your three requests (/adminconsent, /authorize, and /token).  You can find the correlationIds for the first two in the `client-request-id` and `x-ms-request-id` headers of the responses.

Comment: @MichaelMainer-MSFT I use the microsoft graph client library for requesting data.

Comment: @Yina I have used this example for setting up my application. but it also failed when using the scope "User.ReadWrite.All"

Comment: @dstrockis here is the data you requested.

Adminconsent - request ID: ee23085e-7368-4887-b007-29a3763b969c
Date:Thu, 06 Oct 2016 06:55:37 GMT

Authorize - request ID: 1f478c89-7074-4b34-92fb-945fe0328b8c
Date:Thu, 06 Oct 2016 06:56:57 GMT

Token - Correlation ID: 136f818e-125a-48ab-a3e9-c9389b733a6b
Timestamp: 2016-10-06 06:57:41Z

The first 2 IDs I got from the network tab from the browser.
The last ID I got from the error message when requesting the token through MSAL (Microsoft.Identity.Client)

Comment: Great! I'll take a look a little later today.